# Linearly interpolate multiple columns data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, interpolation

I have multiple `data.table` objects, each containing 1-3 measurements from a sensor as time series data. Each sensor has a unique timestamp for measurements and a unique sampling interval, meaning not two `data.tables` have 'matching' time values:

```
> head(particle_counter)
                  time count3 count5 count10
1: 2020-04-17 19:45:08  42436   2848     479
2: 2020-04-17 19:46:08  43757   2999     470
3: 2020-04-17 19:47:08  43107   2967     448
4: 2020-04-17 22:59:27  41516   2394     184
5: 2020-04-17 23:00:27  42571   2645     322
6: 2020-04-17 23:01:27  70994  28007   18477


> head(box_data)
                  time     pm1    pm25    pm10
1: 2020-04-18 00:46:00 1.13658 1.94190 3.56055
2: 2020-04-18 00:47:00 1.23021 2.02457 6.33052
3: 2020-04-18 00:48:00 1.33757 2.16237 5.85435
4: 2020-04-18 00:49:00 1.31169 2.08443 2.95454
5: 2020-04-18 00:50:00 1.52275 2.53015 6.15066
6: 2020-04-18 00:51:00 1.60951 2.23225 2.42537
```

For instance for the above two datasets, I'd like to linearly interpolate all columns of `box_data` for the same time stamps as `particle_counter`. The time stamps in `particle_counter` are in `EST` while `box_data` has them in `UTC` which is why they appear different but point to the same actual time period.

The above data is a very small sample, the actual datasets contain 30,000 rows each.

I can use `approxfun` for individual columns, e.g.:

```
> f1 <- approxfun(x = box_data$time, y = box_data$pm1, method = 'linear')
> f1(v = particle_counter$time)
[1]       NA 1.149064 1.244525 3.137237 2.879353 3.103322
```

Is there a good (elegant) way to apply this to all columns of `box_data` in a single call? I believe there should be a way to do this by using `lapply` over  `.SD` or `.SDcols` but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: maybe something like `box_data[, lapply(.SD, function(y) approx(time, y, particle_counter$time)), .SDcols=pm1:pm10]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 thanks, it works!